# Are Infragistics UltraGrid and Infragistics WinGrid the same product?

Tags: infragistics, ultrawingrid, wingrid

Have some task with Infragistics UltraGrid requirement. Found Infragistics controls' list on their site, but there is no UltraGrid in it, only WinGrid. Please, tell me, are these products the same?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WinGrid™ is what they call the grid control for WinForms apps.  It is often refered to as the UltraGrid because that is how it appears in the DevStudio toolbox.  The actual namespace is Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.

Answer (score 0):

I think they are! think they are name slightly differently between WEB and Widows and maybe even version!

Answer (score 0):

Ig has in its products UltraWebGrid which is a product of the company up to 7.3 release, from 8.3 release the control is named (re-written) WebDataGrid. Ig has just released WebHierarchicalDataGrid.

As for the Windows Forms package WinGrid and Ultra grid are the same as stated before.
You can check for more info at http://help.infragistics.com/